# Export JavaFX model to STL file

Tags: javafx, 3d, java-3d, javafx-3d

I would like to generate some shapes in JavaFX and export it to STL format for 3D printing. Is there a library out there to help with the export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, related to JavaFX 3D, I suggest you have a look at the FXyz [library](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz).

You will find a extense library of custom shapes like: Cone, Pyramid, SegmentedSphere, Spheroid, Torus, SegmentedTorus, Prism, Spring, CurvedSpring, Frustum, Icosahedron, Knot,...

Also, have a look at the sampler [application](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz), where you can try easily all these shapes and the different options (lights, materials, textures, ...).

[image: Sampler application]

Another option is the JCSG [project](https://github.com/miho/JCSG), that will create CSG (Constructive Solid Geometry) shapes with boolean operations.

For the second part, exporting to STL a `TriangleMesh`, as far as I know there's no implementation for JavaFX.

In the mentioned FXyz library you can find an OBJ [exporter](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz/blob/master/src/org/fxyz/utils/OBJWriter.java). Only if you are working with JCSG, there is a STL exporter `CSG.toStlString()`, besides the OBJ one `CSG.toObj()`.

Anyway, once you have your `TriangleMesh`, given the STL [format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29), you can easily create an exporter method:

```
public class MeshUtils {

    public static void mesh2STL(String fileName, Mesh mesh) throws IOException{

        if(!(mesh instanceof TriangleMesh)){
            return;
        }
        // Get faces
        ObservableFaceArray faces = ((TriangleMesh)mesh).getFaces();
        int[] f=new int[faces.size()];
        faces.toArray(f);

        // Get vertices
        ObservableFloatArray points = ((TriangleMesh)mesh).getPoints();
        float[] p = new float[points.size()];
        points.toArray(p);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("solid meshFX\n");

        // convert faces to polygons
        for(int i=0; i<faces.size()/6; i++){
            int i0=f[6*i], i1=f[6*i+2], i2=f[6*i+4];
            Point3D pA=new Point3D(p[3*i0], p[3*i0+1], p[3*i0+2]);
            Point3D pB=new Point3D(p[3*i1], p[3*i1+1], p[3*i1+2]);
            Point3D pC=new Point3D(p[3*i2], p[3*i2+1], p[3*i2+2]);
            Point3D pN=pB.subtract(pA).crossProduct(pC.subtract(pA)).normalize();

            sb.append("  facet normal ").append(pN.getX()).append(" ").append(pN.getY()).append(" ").append(pN.getZ()).append("\n");
            sb.append("    outer loop\n");
            sb.append("      vertex ").append(pA.getX()).append(" ").append(pA.getY()).append(" ").append(pA.getZ()).append("\n");
            sb.append("      vertex ").append(pB.getX()).append(" ").append(pB.getY()).append(" ").append(pB.getZ()).append("\n");
            sb.append("      vertex ").append(pC.getX()).append(" ").append(pC.getY()).append(" ").append(pC.getZ()).append("\n");
            sb.append("    endloop\n");
            sb.append("  endfacet\n");
        }

        sb.append("endsolid meshFX\n");

        // write file
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.forName("UTF-8"),
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING)) {
            writer.write(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can easily export any of the shapes you create:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    FrustumMesh cone = new FrustumMesh(1,0.2,4,2);
    MeshUtils.mesh2STL("frustum.stl", cone.getMesh());

}
```

This is a picture of the exported shape using the 3D model browser from [InteractiveMesh](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dbrowser.html) to load the STL file:

[image: STL]